# how Connection Pool works when I have multiple ec2 Instances?

Tags: node.js, express, pg

When I use the pg Library and I use Connection Pool and I set it to 20

But how should I configure it when I use multiple Instances ? Maybe I have Three instances how should I Change my Connection Pool or can it be the same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.